Source for the permission to imagine Hashem as a person while davening
I have seen mentioned by a Rav the following regarding how we interact with Hashem during tefilah:

"However, when we speak to Hashem, so for our benefit, He gives us permission to imagine that a compassionate old sage is standing in front of us and listening to us; or that a king is sitting on a throne and looking down with kindly eyes upon us and listening to us. Each person can utilize whatever picture is more beneficial to him. So we have a right to think those thoughts, but we should know that these thoughts are only forms meant to help us gain an awareness of Hashem. Actually, Hashem is far above any form that you can ever imagine. אין לו דמות הגוף ואינו גוף. So, therefore, both things are true. We have the right to picture Hashem in order to gain more awareness of Him, and nevertheless, we know that Hashem is exalted above all forms that we could ever imagine."

Does anyone know the source of this concept that we have 'permission' to imagine Hashem with a face during davening?

I think the Raavad says something like this.

I think this question was asked before, serious deja vu

https://www.sefaria.org/Bnei_Machshava_Tova,_Principles_and_Advice_7.4
https://www.sefaria.org/Bnei_Machshava_Tova,_Principles_and_Advice_7.9

I think you are inserting your own personal interpretation on the Rabbis wording.
The rabbi is saying that we must imagine saying our Tefilot the same way we would beg for something from a Dignitary or King, or from a wise man who holds all the answers. He is (by דרך המשל) trying to anthropomorphize the Tefilot to be relatable, much like the posuk says Moshe spoke to Hashem like one would speak to his friend.
As to imagining Hashem Yitborach with some sort of image, see Rabbeinu Saadia Gaon’s pirush on Hazon Daniyel. Even if the rabbi meant to literally imagine some sort of resemblance of God, this can be tied to understanding Daniyel HaNovi’s vision of Hashem siting on his throne, that both Hashem and the Throne are not actually physically being seen as they are both far beyond anything physical or even spiritual. The throne of God is to be understood as the Emanated Glory of God’s power in the lower worlds
So rather it is to be understood as imagining Hashems great power that he reveals to us everyday and moment להודיע לבני אדם גבורותיו וכבוד הדר מלכותו
